# Paging over a lazy-loaded collection with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections, pagination, lazy-loading

I read [this article](http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/nhibernate-vs.-entity-framework-4.0.aspx) where Ayende states NHibernate can (compared to EF 4):

> - Collection with lazy=”extra” – Lazy extra means that NHibernate adapts to
>     the operations that you might run on
>     top of your collections. That means
>     that blog.Posts.Count will not force a
>     load of the entire collection, but
>     rather would create a “select count(*)
>     from Posts where BlogId = 1”
>     statement, and that
>     blog.Posts.Contains() will likewise
>     result in a single query rather than
>     paying the price of loading the entire
>     collection to memory.
> - Collection filters and paged collections  - this allows you to
>     define additional filters (including
>     paging!) on top of your entities
>     collections, which means that you can
>     easily page through the blog.Posts
>     collection, and not have to load the
>     entire thing into memory.

So I decided to put together a test case. I created the cliché Blog model as a simple demonstration, with two classes as follows:

```
public class Blog
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set;  }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; private set;  }

    public virtual void AddPost(Post item)
    {
        if (Posts == null) Posts = new List<Post>();
        if (!Posts.Contains(item)) Posts.Add(item);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; private set; }
}
```

My mappings files look like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="Model.Blog, TestEntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="Blogs">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Name" />
    </property>
    <property name="Type" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Type" />
    </property>
    <bag lazy="extra" name="Posts">
      <key>
        <column name="Blog_Id" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="Model.Post, TestEntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="Model.Post, TestEntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="Posts">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Title" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Title" />
    </property>
    <property name="Body" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Body" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="Model.Blog, TestEntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Blog">
      <column name="Blog_id" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My test case looks something like this:

```
        using (ISession session = Configuration.Current.CreateSession()) // this class returns a custom ISession that represents either EF4 or NHibernate
        {
            blogs = (from b in session.Linq<Blog>()
                         where b.Name.Contains("Test")
                         orderby b.Id
                         select b);

            Console.WriteLine("# of Blogs containing 'Test': {0}", blogs.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("Viewing the first 5 matching Blogs.");

            foreach (Blog b in blogs.Skip(0).Take(5))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Blog #{0} \"{1}\" has {2} Posts.", b.Id, b.Name, b.Posts.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Viewing first 5 matching Posts.");

                foreach (Post p in b.Posts.Skip(0).Take(5))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Post #{0} \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", p.Id, p.Title, p.Body);
                }
            }
        }
```

Using **lazy="extra"**, the call to `b.Posts.Count` does do a `SELECT COUNT(Id)...` which is great. However, `b.Posts.Skip(0).Take(5)` just grabs all Posts for Blog.Id = ?id, and then LINQ on the application side is just taking the first 5 from the resulting collection.

What gives?

Comment: +1 for a good question. I've been wondering about NHibernates lazy loading capabilities for awhile now but haven't had the time to try them out.

Comment: maybe the LINQ to NHibernate part regarding collection filters is not implemented

Comment: Just one caveat for using lazy="extra". We started using this on our application and everything worked fine until we deployed to a Sql Server 2000 machine (still the client's approved software).

Because we use a guid as our identity fields, we started getting the exception, 'Cannot perform count on unique identifier' (approx). I looked at the NH source code and found it was the extra lazy load that chooses the first key column and does 'select count(<columName>)', which was our GUID field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure (reading the comments) that he's talking about the CreateFilter of ISession.

You can do paging like this (from the docs 13.13):

```
Collections are pageable by using the IQuery interface with a filter:

IQuery q = s.CreateFilter( collection, "" ); // the trivial filter
q.setMaxResults(PageSize); 
q.setFirstResult(PageSize * pageNumber); 
IList page = q.List();
```

Or (from the docs 17.1.4):

```
s.CreateFilter( lazyCollection, "").SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResults(10).List();
```

That's is not as smooth as using the System.Linq methods. I guess they'll join the syntax some time too.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. disappointingly unsmooth. But, that'll do. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Would it be possible to post the original example, with this technique implemented? Thanks.