# NHibernate - Limiting results from eagerly fetched collections

Tags: nhibernate

I've been taking a look at the [NHProf](http://nhprof.com) Nhibernate profiler (Really great tool, but unfortunately priced a bit too highly in my opinion).  And it is raises a warning that there is an 'unbounded result set' (the child collection)for my queries of this type (eagerly fetched child collections):

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<SomeType>()
                .SetFetchMode("ChildCollection", FetchMode.Eager)
                .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(id));
```

**My question is, how *should* I be handling this type of query?  Is there a way to limit the eagerly fetched results somehow?**

The other problem I suppose is that with a limited collection, how to access further results when needed?  (I mean I guess there is no lazy loaded after you have populated it). Please tell me if I'm not explaining myself clearly!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can [page over the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430863/paging-over-a-lazy-loaded-collection-with-nhibernate) but if you know that collection isn't going to be huge then I'd just ignore that alert. There is also the `batch-size` [collection mapping](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping) parameter.